# create records in more than one object

Tags: lookup, data-loader

I have two objects A and B. When I import data and create record from a csv file in A I need that it's created the same record with the same Id in the B object. Is it possible?

Comment: what do you mean by same id. is it lookup in object B? you can't do that using data loader but you can do using composite rest API.

Comment: yes, sorry I need to insert data with csv file in a object, and display the same data in the releated list in another object.

Comment: Salesforce basic to use ids in relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you import your data for Object A, you should get a success file that contains the IDs of object A records.  You can then use this success file to import Object B records and map the Object A Ids to the lookup field in Object B.